# Ruby on Rails activerecord reputation system for average rating and total number of ratings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am using activerecord_reputation_system gem to rate something, let's call it model X. In app/models/x.rb I have

```
has_reputation :rating, source: :user, aggregated_by: :average
```

This lets me view the average rating.

My question: how can I view both average rating and total number of votes for model X? One way would be to add to app/models/x.rb:

```
has_reputation :rating, source: :user, aggregated_by: :average
has_reputation :reviews, source: :user, aggregated_by: :sum
```

and in the controller have:

```
value = params[:rating]
@x = X.find(params[:id])
if X.where(id: params[:id]).evaluated_by(:reviews, current_user).blank?
  @x.add_or_update_evluation(:reviews, 1, current_user)
end
@x.add_or_update_evaluation(:rating, value, current_user)
```

Is this the best way to do it or is there a better way?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do in this way :

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :x
 attr_accessible :rate #it can be in range 1..5

 def rating
  rate
 end
end    

 class X < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :votes

 def average_rating
   unless votes.empty?
    (self.votes.sum(&:rating)/number_of_votes.to_f).round
   end
 end

 def number_of_votes
  self.votes.count
 end
end
```

Also you can use gem: https://github.com/muratguzel/letsrate

Let me know if this is a good solution .